# "Object contains only the public half of a key pair. A private key must also be provided." Using 2 .pem's & X509 & MS Services3.Security

Tags: certificate, x509, pem, key-pair

Here's the code:

```
using ADPTest.com.adp.hrbws;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security;
using Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Cryptography;

namespace ADPTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create the web service proxy.
            HrbService proxy = new HrbService();

            // Add the Username token.
            UsernameToken usernameToken = new UsernameToken("user@ABC"," ");
            proxy.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(usernameToken);

            // Add the certificate for mutual SSL.
            X509Certificate2 mutualCert = new X509Certificate2 "I:\\auth.pem", " ");
            proxy.ClientCertificates.Add(mutualCert);

            // Sign the message using the signing certificate.
            X509Certificate2 signCert = new X509Certificate2("I:\\soap.pem", " ");
            X509SecurityToken signatureToken = new X509SecurityToken(signCert);
            MessageSignature signature = new MessageSignature(signatureToken);
            proxy.RequestSoapContext.Security.Elements.Add(signature);
```

I think that mutualCert, auth, is my public cert and signCert, SOAP, is my private cert, but I'm really not sure. I took the code from a sort of (web service) cookbook...  The web service says that they don't look at the passwords.

The error message is:

> "Object contains only the public half of a key pair. A private key must also be provided."

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the .pem file to a .pfx for the .Net framework to be able to use it. The .pfx will contain both the public and private keys. You can use OpenSSL to convert the .pem file that ADP sent you to a .pfx file.

http://www.openssl.org/

mutualCert is the SSL certificate for connecting to ADP
signCert is used for your SOAP/webservice calls

I've been working on an inerface with ADP for several months and I'm still having problems.

Hope this helps
-Doug